# Creating a java loop that has one variable go up to 99 while the other variable goes down to 0

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

Hard to explain, sorry in advance. I'm trying to add distances between 99 different variables. I'm putting them all in a hashmap. I was thinking the best way to do it would be (1, 2, distance), and then (1,3,distance) and all the way until I've mapped a distance between all 99 of them. So one variable has to go up to 98 and the other has to go up to 99, and then to 98, etc. I've no idea how to do this. I tried doing a nested for loop but that doesn't seem to work.

```
    for (int i=0; i<99; i++)
{
    for (int j=99; j>0; i--)
    {
        graphWeighted.addEdge(nodelist.get(i), nodelist.get(j), distances.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
for (int i=0; i < 99; i++) {
    for (int j=i+1; j < 100; j++) {
        graphWeighted.addEdge(nodelist.get(i), nodelist.get(j), distances.get(i));
    }
}
```

The above doubly-nested loop would generate pairs including:

```
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
...
(0, 99)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
...
(1, 99)
...
(98, 99)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find a distance between two vector elements then you need to use any one of the distance algorithms `Manhatten` or `Euclidean`. You may have to use external third-party library to perform such operations.

Apache commons library contains a package `org.apache.commons.math3.ml.distance` and classes to perform L1 and L2 norms on the vectors.

Please check the documentation [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4.1/org/apache/commons/math3/ml/distance/package-summary.html)